# Run VSCode tasks in a single session

Tags: linux, terminal, visual-studio-code, root, sudo

I would like to migrate my local deployment commands to VSCode task. I need to run them as root. When I did those in the terminal, I was asked to provide the password only once.

```
$ sudo echo hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[sudo] password for pt12lol: 
hello
$ sudo echo hello                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
hello
```

Unfortunately when I configured my VSCode task:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Hello task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "sudo echo hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

I suppose it runs every task in a separate session, and I am asked to provide my password every single time.

```
> Executing task: sudo echo hello <

[sudo] password for pt12lol: 
hello

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

> Executing task: sudo echo hello <

[sudo] password for pt12lol: 
hello

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Is it possible to set up tasks deployment so that it keeps last sessions and I am not asked for my password?

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this problem also, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/275505/run-a-sudo-command-specifying-the-password-on-the-same-line) question helped me out. In Linux you can't explicitly pass in a password to `sudo`, but there's ways around that.

`echo password | sudo -S command`

will pipe `password` into sudo using the `-S` argument. From the [sudo man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> -S The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.

Modifying your code produced the desired effects on my machine.

```
{
    {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Hello task",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo password | sudo -S echo hello"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This way you are keeping your decrypted password in your processes tree or on your HDD. Highly insecure. I don't like it.

Comment: Read the man pages, I don't think `sudo` allows for another way. This worked in my case because I'm building on a remote development machine where password encryption isn't important. Your mileage may vary :-)

Comment: You could also try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/643146). It seems like it will only require a password once per log in session, this is system wide though.

Comment: Working on remote machines with no decrypted password is for me ESPECIALLY important, because in most cases you are not the only server user, so anyone else using this machine can read your password using `ps` listing and do things as you.

Comment: I'm aware of the risks. I'm not sure the functionality you are looking for exists in `sudo`. Check out the linked answer in my last comment for a different approach.

Comment: @pt12lol I'm not sure if this would work, but would `cat password.txt | sudo -S` also keep the password in the process tree?