# VScode Task run while maintaining sudo

Tags: sudo, vscode-tasks

I would like to run a task that needs sudo and not need to authenticate each time. Rather I'd like to authenticate the first time and then again after it expires like I do in a terminal.

It is similar to these questions:
[Is there any way of running VSCode tasks in the *current* integrated terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67845156/is-there-any-way-of-running-vscode-tasks-in-the-current-integrated-terminal?rq=3)
[Run VSCode tasks in a single session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57304851/run-vscode-tasks-in-a-single-session) but they aren't helpful here.

It's unacceptable to keep the password somewhere unencrypted, and `"panel":"dedicated/shared"` doesn't persist that sudo has been entered between calls. I somewhat suspect this is not possible, but I'd appreciate confirmation.